# Adding input values and default values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this short form that when the user selects the first option in a dropdown menu, three fields will appear. The first field has a default value while the other two should be fill up by the user. Then I need to get the total of the three fields. If the user selcts the second option, the three fields will not appear. As of now, this is what I've got:

**HTML**

```
<select id="select1">
    <option value="A">New</option>
    <option value="B>Satisfied</option>
</select>

<div id="d1>
    <label>This is a default value</label><input type="text" id="input1" placeholder="$75,000" style="width: 100px;"/>
    <label>Preferred Value:</label><input type="text" id="input2" value="" style="width: 100px;"/>
    <label>Number of Contributors:</label><input type="text" id="input3" value="" style="width: 100px;"/>
    <label>Total:</label><input type="text" id="txt1" value=""/>
</div>
```

**jquery**

```
$("#select1").change(function(){
        if($(event.target).val() == 'A'){
            $('#d1').show();
        }else{
            $('#d1').hide();
        }
    });
```

**js**

```
function total(){
    var a = $("#input1").val();
    var b = $("#input2").val();
    var c = $("#input3").val();

    var d = parseFloat(a, 10);
    var e = parseFloat(a, 10);
    var f = parseFloat(a, 10);

    total = d + e + f;
    $('#txt1').val(total.toFixed(2));$(
}
```

Comment: so what is the problem?

Comment: And your problem is?

Comment: I get a `NaN` in my total. I don't know if I did the right thing in calling the input that the user type.

Answer (score 0):

As stated, i's not clear what the question is. I'm assuming you're problem is it just doesn't work. Looking at your code it wouldn't. I re-wrote some of your stuff and I think this is what you are looking for

```
$("#select1").change(function(event){
  if($(this).val() == 'A'){
    $('#d1').show();
  }else{
    $('#d1').hide();
  }
});

$("input").blur(function(){
  total();
});

function total(){
  var a,b,c = 0;

  var a = $("#input1").val();
  var b = $("#input2").val();
  var c = $("#input3").val();

  if(a != ""){
    var d = parseFloat(a, 10);
  }else{
    var d = 0;
  }

  if(b != ""){
    var e = parseFloat(b, 10);
  }else{
    var e = 0;
  }

  if(c != ""){
    var f = parseFloat(c, 10);
  }else{
    var f = 0;
  }    

  var calcTotal = d + e + f;
   $('#txt1').val(calcTotal.toFixed(2));
}
```

You're getting NaN cause it's trying to float a number that doesn't exist. You can check to see if that field has a value and if not render 0

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/t0o7uz9d/2/)

**UPDATE**

That's simple enough, just reset the values when you hide the div

[NEW FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/t0o7uz9d/3/)

Comment: thank you.
my first question is answered now. but still, the value in the total is not changing. the total should return to 0 if the customer chooses the "satisfied" or if the three fields is on hide

Answer (score 0):

Simply copy and paste code. It is same code as yours, I have done some basic modification in Jquery and there was also mistakes in your html.......plz check it, it will work perfectly.     thnx

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script >
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $("#select1").change(function(){
        if($(event.target).val() == 'A'){
            $('#d1').show();
        }else{
            $('#d1').hide();
        }
    });
});

 </script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function total(){

    var a = $("#input1").val();
    var b = $("#input2").val();
    var c = $("#input3").val();

    var d = parseFloat(a, 10);
    var e = parseFloat(a, 10);
    var f = parseFloat(a, 10);

    total = d + e + f;
   document.getElementById('txt1').value=total;
}
</script>

</head>

<body>
<select id="select1">
    <option value="A">New</option>
    <option value="B">Satisfied</option>
</select>

<div id="d1">
    <label>This is a default value</label><input type="text" id="input1" placeholder="$75,000" style="width: 100px;"/>
    <label>Preferred Value:</label><input type="text" id="input2" value="" style="width: 100px;"/>
    <label>Number of Contributors:</label><input type="text" id="input3" value="" style="width: 100px;"/>
    <label>Total:</label><input type="text" id="txt1" value="" onclick="total();" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this: And please do change your html also they have some error like in select for B you have not closed `"`.

```js
$("#select1").change(function(event){
    if($(event.target).val() == 'A'){
        $('#d1').show();
    }else{
        $('#d1').hide();
   $('#txt1').val(0);

    }
});

$("input").on('blur',function(){
total();
 
});

function total(){
    var a = $("#input1").val();
    var b = $("#input2").val();
    var c = $("#input3").val();
    var total=0;
if(a.length > 0){
    var d = parseFloat(a, 10);
    total=total+d;
}
if(b.length > 0){
    var e = parseFloat(b, 10);
    total=total+e;
}
if(c.length > 0){
    var f = parseFloat(c, 10); 
    total=total+f;
}

    $('#txt1').val(total.toFixed(2));

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select1">
    <option value="A">New</option>
    <option value="B">Satisfied</option>
</select>

<div id="d1">
    <label>This is a default value</label><input type="text" id="input1" placeholder="$75,000" style="width: 100px;" >
    <label>Preferred Value:</label><input type="text" id="input2" value="" style="width: 100px;" />
    <label>Number of Contributors:</label><input type="text" id="input3" value="" style="width: 100px;" />
    <label>Total:</label><input type="text" id="txt1" value=""/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $("#select1").change(function() {
    $('#d1').toggle($(this).val() == 'A');
  });

  $('#input1, #input2, #input3').change(total)

  function total() {
    var a = $("#input1").val();
    var b = $("#input2").val();
    var c = $("#input3").val();

    var d = parseFloat(a, 10) || 0;
    var e = parseFloat(b, 10) || 0;
    var f = parseFloat(c, 10) || 0;

    total = d + e + f;
    $('#txt1').val(total.toFixed(2));
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select1">
  <option value="A">New</option>
  <option value="B">Satisfied</option>
</select>
<div id="d1">
  <label>This is a default value</label>
  <input type="text" id="input1" placeholder="$75,000" style="width: 100px;" />
  <label>Preferred Value:</label>
  <input type="text" id="input2" value="" style="width: 100px;" />
  <label>Number of Contributors:</label>
  <input type="text" id="input3" value="" style="width: 100px;" />
  <label>Total:</label>
  <input type="text" id="txt1" value="" />
</div>
```